# How do you use ignition gazebo?

Tags: gazebo-ignition, gazebo-edifice

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Trying to use ignition Gazebo with the following command

```
ign gazebo world.sdf
```

but it doesn't load and I don't get any feedback

Looking at the help it doesn't actually seem to have that command

```
The 'ign' command provides a command line interface to the ignition tools.

  ign <command> [options]

List of available commands:

  help:          Print this help text.
  msg:           Print information about messages.
  topic:         Print information about topics.
  service:       Print information about services.
  fuel:          Manage simulation resources.
  log:           Record or playback topics.
  sdf:           Utilities for SDF files.

Options:

  --force-version <VERSION>  Use a specific library version.
  --versions                 Show the available versions.
  --commands                 Show the available commands.
Use 'ign help <command>' to print help for a command.
```

Using `apt list`

```
libignition-gazebo3-dbg/unknown 3.8.0-1~focal amd64
libignition-gazebo3-dev/unknown 3.8.0-1~focal amd64
libignition-gazebo3-plugins/unknown 3.8.0-1~focal amd64
libignition-gazebo3/unknown 3.8.0-1~focal amd64
libignition-gazebo4-dbg/unknown 4.7.0-1~focal amd64
libignition-gazebo4-dev/unknown 4.7.0-1~focal amd64
libignition-gazebo4-plugins/unknown 4.7.0-1~focal amd64
libignition-gazebo4/unknown 4.7.0-1~focal amd64
libignition-gazebo5-dbg/unknown 5.0.0-1~focal amd64
libignition-gazebo5-dev/unknown 5.0.0-1~focal amd64
libignition-gazebo5-plugins/unknown 5.0.0-1~focal amd64
libignition-gazebo5/unknown 5.0.0-1~focal amd64
```

on Ubuntu 20.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26846/how-do-you-use-ignition-gazebo?/) by [cjds](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/45888/cjds/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The missing support you are looking for is being currently shipped in `cmdgazeboX.rb` files (where X is the major version)

```
~ ❯ dpkg -L libignition-gazebo5-dev | grep cmd.*.rb
   /usr/lib/ruby/ignition/cmdgazebo5.rb
```

I would recommend to follow [install instructions](https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/edifice/install_ubuntu) and use the latest metapackage avaiable (Edifice release in the moment of writing this). The metapackage should leave everything ready to run.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2021-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1